# Nextjs simplest prosemirror setup that enables to set content on change of props

Tags: reactjs, next.js, wysiwyg, draftjs, prose-mirror

I want to do a simple prosemirror editor with nextjs app. Here is what I tried to do

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { EditorState } from "prosemirror-state";
import { EditorView } from "prosemirror-view";
import { Schema, DOMParser } from "prosemirror-model";
import { schema } from "prosemirror-schema-basic";
import { addListNodes } from "prosemirror-schema-list";
import { exampleSetup } from "prosemirror-example-setup";

const Editor = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const mySchema = new Schema({
      nodes: addListNodes(schema.spec.nodes, "paragraph block*", "block"),
      marks: schema.spec.marks,
    });

    new EditorView(document.querySelector("#editor"), {
      state: EditorState.create({
        doc: DOMParser.fromSchema(mySchema).parse(
          document.querySelector("#content")
        ),
        plugins: exampleSetup({ schema: mySchema }),
      }),
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div id="editor"></div>
      <div id="content"></div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Editor;
```

One issue is that it duplicates the editor as in the picture below [image]

However the main issue is I want to be able to highlight the content of the editor when the state of a variable changes. For example I want to define a variable that holds the value of the index of the word that I want to highlight. When that value changes I want to update the contents of the editor to highlight that specific word. That's all I want. I looked around the documentation but it is a bit difficult to understand. I appreciate any hints. I have looked into draftjs as well with no luck.

Comment: does prosemirror use draftjs?